# Replacing a string with a variable in all the files

Tags: linux, perl

I am trying to replace a string     "ABC" with     ".$VAR." running the below command.

```
perl -p -i -e "s/ABC/\.\$VAR\./g" *
```

This makes the string as ".." instead of ".$VAR".Please can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong here??

Answer (score 1):

1. You don't need to escape .  on the replace side since it isn't a
   pattern
2. Just use single quotes around the body so the shell
   doesn't interpolate $VAR

Answer (score 1):

Use single quotes:

```
perl -i -pe 's/ABC/.\$VAR\./g' *
```

Otherwise, you're only escaping $VAR on the shell and not perl level.  If you want to use double quotes, you'll need to use 3 backslashes.

```
perl -i -pe "s/ABC/.\\\$VAR\./g" *
```

Answer (score 1):

Perl variables start with `$`, as well as shell variables. You correctly inserted `\` before the `$VAR`, but it only prevents the expansion of the variable on the shell level, not Perl level. Add more backslashes or switch to single quotes.

```
perl -i~ -pe "s/ABC/.\\\$VAR./g" *
```

or

```
perl -i~ -pe 's/ABC/.\$VAR./g' *
```